# How to keep focus when AJAX updates dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code which is calling a php page that grabs data from a DB table and updates a dropdown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh()
{
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
Console.log("Grabbing Value");
req.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
document.getElementById('monitor').innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
}
req.open("GET", 'test.php?lang=<?php echo $lng;?>', true);
req.send(null);
}
function init()
{
refresh()
var int=self.setInterval(function(){refresh()},3000);
}
</script>
```

This is working fine but my problem is, when I have an item in the drop down box selected and then this gets updated, the drop down box goes to the 1st item.

Is there any way for ajax to leave what I have highlighted and still update the dropdown box?

Comment: So you would need to remember the form values and reselect it after the update. Or better yest, only change the section of code that gets updated if it is not the entire thing.

Comment: Thanks. the test.php page only has a dropdown for now and is getting populated properly. The end goal will have a few dozen drop downs on that page where each drop down is pulling from a different table. Would there be a more efficient or easier way to do this without having to remember the form values of each drop down?